# 'id<MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>'from incompatible type 'ViewController *const_strong'

Tags: objective-c, xcode, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

In my app I have a button that when pressed opens a email whit filled out "to" and "subject", but I get this warning on this line of code:

```
mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
```

The warning says:

`Assigning to 'id<MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>'from incompatible type 'ViewController *const_strong'`

What do I do? Please be very clear, I am not too skilled in xCode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This warning says that you haven't told the compiler that your class `ViewController` implements the [`MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate) protocol.

If you haven't done it, implement all the required methods from that protocol. In your case it's only one (`– mailComposeController:didFinishWithResult:error:`).

After that you have to tell the compiler that your class implements this protocol. You do this by adding `<MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>` to the `@interface` of ViewController. (The interface is in your header file, ViewController.h).

Your interface should now look similar to this:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>

@property ...

@end
```

Comment: Thank you, does this really change anything? The app worked fine even with the warning?

Comment: It's there to help you. The compiler want's to make sure that you know that mailComposeDelegate requires you to implement the methods from the protocol. And if you put the confirmation declaration in your interface, and you forgot to implement required methods, the compiler will put out another warning. Just to help you implement all the methods. Sometimes there are required methods that are only called in very unlike circumstances. If you wouldn't have implemented such a method your app would crash.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. The problem was that I was implementing the wrong protocol, and I suspect you might be doing the same thing.

In your view controller header file do NOT write:
`@interface ViewController : UIViewController <MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate>`

Instead, use:
`@interface ViewController : UIViewController <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>.`